# How to negate a movement in css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'd like to know how to compute or negate the movement of an element if its parent element has a transition applied to it.

For example, I have a carousel which has the following markup:

```
<ul class="carousel" style="position:relative;">
<li class="item active">
    text content 1. Will move with the slide.
    <div class="fixed-content">
     I want to remain where I am and I have the exact same content as the fixed element below
    </div>
<li>
<li class="item">
    text content 2. Will move with the slide.
    <div class="fixed-content">
     I want to remain where I am and I have the exact same content as the fixed element above
    </div>
<li>
</ul>
```

Then during the transition when active switches from item to item, it adds a class left/right, prev/next, depending on which div is going to be active next. then removes these classes afterwards.

If it has those classes, it will apply a css transform: translateX(-100%) [or transform: translateX(100%)] to the .item element and it has a transition duration of .6s and an ease-out option.

Now, I want to use css animation to the .fixed-content to make it look "static" or "fixed". How do I write that in the animation keyframe? and what's formula to use to compute if the transition duration has changed?

PS. I know, I could just re-arrange the elements so that I can put .fixed-content outside of the .items and assign it a position:absolute property, but let's just pretend I am not able to do that. ;)

Comment: Just try `position: fixed` !

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say position:fixed is not an option because of a problem inherent in it's nature: it stays fixed in position even if you scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this markup and its just a kick hover effect (not carroussel), but I believe is something like this.

http://codepen.io/joaosaro/pen/oLZmRr

```
<ul class="carousel" style="position:relative;">
  <div class="wrap">
    <li class="item one">text content 1. Will move with the slide.</li>
    <li class="item two">text content 2. Will move with the slide.</li>
    <div class="fixed-content">I want to remain where I am and I have the exact same content as the fixed element above</div>
  </div>
</ul>


ul {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul .wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul .wrap li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
ul .wrap li.one {
  background-color: yellow;
}
ul .wrap li.two {
  background-color: red;
}
ul .wrap .fixed-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
ul:hover .wrap li {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
          transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm thinking the div.fixed-content should be inside the the 2 li.item.

Comment: Why. Shouldn't be the same? You want to change strings?

Comment: "I want to remain where I am and I have the exact same content as the fixed element above"

Comment: Because, the content inside the li.item is controlled via CMS and the users aren't allowed to put elements outside of the li.item. (It's pretty complicated, but at this point, we can't change the system)

Comment: So, its not the same content. :p

Comment: Technically it's not the same content, but the user will probably put in the same content, duplicated among the li.item...